# I don't understand stable algorithm definition

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> In computer science, a stable sorting algorithm preserves the order of records with equal keys.

I just don't understand why certain sorting algorithm are stable and others none. A basic sorting algorithm orders items of an array of int. If I create a class or a struct and I use the same algorithm considering swapping of the whole object, and choosing to order it by key, o by age ecc, then every algorithm can preserve the order of records!

I think I missed something about the definition.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a practical programming question. It's a theoretical question. (A quick search for "stable sort" turns up [Why is selection sort not stable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601057/why-is-selection-sort-not-stable) which gives an example of a nonstable sort.)

Comment: Seems like you've pretty much answered your own question in the first line. But why do you say "Then every algorithm can preserve the order of records" ? - Not every sort algoritm is guaranteed to preserve order of records with equal keys. [For example Heapsort.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)

Comment: You are confused because in your mind, "every zero is the same as any other zero". That may be true when doing arithmetic, but it is not when considering the result of sorting a set. Real world parallel: every can of Coke in a six-pack is the same as any of the others, but if we are drinking them and you switch your can with mine I might very well object.

Comment: +1. But why negative votes? Fail to understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have an array like the following:

```
a = [5, 4, 2a, 2b, 1]
```

Where the `a` and `b` are simply there to denote that the first 2 (`2a`) comes before the second 2 (`2b`). In a stable sorting algorithm, the result will be:

```
a_stable = [1, 2a, 2b, 4, 5]
```

That is, the *relative order* of the elements hasn't changed - `2a` came before `2b` in the original array, and it remains that way in the sorted array.

With a non-stable algorithm, the result could be:

```
a_nonstable = [1, 2b, 2a, 4, 5]
```

This is still correctly sorted, it's just that the positions relative to where they were in the original, unsorted array have now changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the PATIENT explaination.